# how to make an "on-off" music button?

Tags: button, audio, pygame

I have a problem with pygame. I would like to know how can i do like a "on/off" button of a song on my game .

```
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
  if event.pos[0] > 35 and event.pos[0] < 105 and event.pos[1] > 460 and event.pos[1] < 565: 
    if pygame.mixer.music.play(): 
       pygame.mixer.music.pause() 
    elif pygame.mixer.music.pause():
       pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

Thanks in advance, sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You should explain what's the problem with your code. It isn't working? It throws an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't ask for `pygame.mixer.music.play()` in the `if` condition, because that's the `play` function not a state.

Instead keep the state in a variable:

```
music_playing = True
pygame.mixer.music.play()

...
while ...:

    for events...:

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
            if event.pos[0] > 35 and event.pos[0] < 105 and event.pos[1] > 460 and event.pos[1] < 565: 
                if music_playing: 
                   pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                   music_playing = False
                else:
                   pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                   music_playing = True
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. I just put a "else" instead of "elif" and now it work.